# Highcharts: X and Y Axis cross at zero in scatter chart

Tags: highcharts

In highcharts, I want to plot a scatter/bubble chart where the x values range from -50 to +50, and the y values from -100 to +100. Is there a way to get the x and y axis to be plotted so that they cross at zero in the center of the chart ?

I've tried using the 'offset' parameter in the axis, which does move the axis, e.g. http://bit.ly/Xd9Z51 but this approach has the following problems:

1. You can't set the offset parameter dynamically, so if a series updates and changes the min/max x/y values, the axis no longer cross at zero.
2. If you zoom, the axis no longer cross at zero.
3. It's quite hard to calculate the offsets in pixels, taking into account div size, margins, titles etc.
4. Resizing the containing div causes the required axis offset positions to change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution for Highcharts v7.2+**

Force some options to prevent chart from reserving space for axes, then use plugin:

```js
(function(H) {
  H.addEvent(
    H.Axis,
    'init',
    function(e) {
      if (H.defined(e.userOptions.matchAxis)) {
        H.merge(
          true,
          e.userOptions, {
            labels: {
              reserveSpace: false
            },
            title: {
              reserveSpace: false
            },
            offset: -1,
            opposite: this.isXAxis ? true : false
          }
        );
      }
    }
  );

  H.addEvent(
    H.Chart,
    'render',
    function() {
      let chart = this;

      chart.axes.forEach(function(axis) {

        let newOffset,
          matchAxis = axis.options.matchAxis,
          translate = axis.horiz ? 'translateY' : 'translateX',
          newTranslation = {},
          offset = axis.options.offset || 0,
          crisp = axis.options.lineWidth % 2,
          otherAxes = axis.isXAxis ? chart.yAxis : chart.xAxis;

        if (H.defined(matchAxis)) {
          newOffset = otherAxes[matchAxis.index || 0].toPixels(matchAxis.value || 0, true);

          newTranslation[translate] = newOffset + offset + crisp;

          if (axis.axisGroup) {
            axis.axisGroup.animate(newTranslation);
          }
          if (axis.labelGroup) {
            axis.labelGroup.animate(newTranslation);
          }
        }
      });
    }
  );
})(Highcharts);
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2k0bw6q3/

Plugin's API:

- `x/yAxis.matchAxis.value` - set value that should be picked from the opposite axis. Defaults to 0.
- `x/yAxis.matchAxis.index` - when using multiple axes, set index which opposite axis should be used for calculations. Defaults to 0.

Setting e.g. `yAxis.matchAxis = {}` is completely fine: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qwyczoxb/ (because of defaults)

List of options that are forced (in plugin):

- `x/yAxis.labels.reserveSpace` to false
- `x/yAxis.title.reserveSpace` to false
- `x/yAxis.offset` to a negative value (e.g. -50)
- `xAxis.opposite` is set to true
- `yAxis.opposite` is set to false

**Note:** Tested only with **v7.2.0**

**Old solution (v3+)**

Right now the only solution is to use offset parameter. However since Highcharts 3.0 you can control freely that property and update axis:

```
chart.yAxis[index].update( options );
```

Where options is an object with options for yAxis, including offset. To get pixel position, you can use inner function `chart.xAxis[index].translate(value)` (little hacky, but works). So when both are combined, see example: http://jsfiddle.net/UGpPV/6/

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. Exactly what I wanted to know. Do you have a release date for Highcharts 3.0 ?

Comment: Is there any way I can use 'transform' to move an axis ?

Comment: It depends on how many bugs will we found in beta. We assume to release Highcharts 3.0 in March, see: http://www.highcharts.com/support/roadmap

Comment: Where in the documentation would I find this "translate" function and others like it, or is it not documented?

Comment: Translate is inner method. Now you can use [toPixels()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.toPixels()) and [toValue()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.toValue())