# How to create 2 axis and 2 yaxis in highchart

Tags: c#, highcharts

It's possible to create graph like this picture

[image]

Can create like this or not or any choice to tell me . Thank you.

Comment: Yes http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/6/Crossing-Specific-Values

Answer (score 1):

You can move the y-axis using the y-axis 'offset'.

```
yAxis: {
      offset:-150,
  },
```

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.offset

The documentation refers to a jsfiddle which positions the y-axis to the center of the plot:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/yaxis/offset-centered/

This question ([Highcharts: X and Y Axis cross at zero in scatter chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15140426/highcharts-x-and-y-axis-cross-at-zero-in-scatter-chart)) covers some more detailed issues, including translating data values to pixels to calculate the offset.